# Python - search list with only a few characters entered

Tags: python, string, list

I want to find the string that the user searches for.
For example, if the user enters FD-2** (he doesnt know what the * characters are), the search should give FD-234 and FD-285.
I have a piece of code:

```
rendszam = input('Adja meg a rendszámot! ')
matching = [s for s in rszamok if rendszam in s]
print(matching)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: should the search also match `foooFD-236babf`?

Comment: It can also be the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> targets = 'FD-234 XY-456 FD-285 XY-890 FD-999'
>>> search = 'FD-2**'
>>> pattern = search.replace('*', '.')
>>> re.findall(pattern, targets)
['FD-234', 'FD-285']
```

Comment: Could you do that for me? I am new to python. Thanks

Comment: more appropriate `pattern = search.replace('*', r'\d')`

Comment: But how can I put a list instead of 'targets'? Because I get the error: return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer